# Embedding Jzy3D in an applet

Tags: java, 3d, applet, jogl, jzy3d

I'm trying to make an applet that displays a Jzy3D graph that's manipulable. Currently I've managed to get it to display the graph but I can't affect it in anyway; this makes sense as the applet currently isn't looking for any user input.

How am I supposed to pick up user input (the mouse moving, clicking, etc)? I suppose I could try to make a messenger class that picks up applet input and sends it to Jzy3D which then takes the movement and does things with it but that seems very complicated. <s>Looking at the [Community Discussion Board](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jzy3d/applet/jzy3d/jhgtHmq8jpc/8Uxg7DGMvoMJ), it was suggested to use JOGLAppletLaucher. Is the point of that to bypass this problem? If so, how is it supposed to do so?</s>

**EDIT:** I believe I understand now the point of JOGLAppletLauncher (and its succesor JNLPAppletLauncher) but the question of how to transmit user input still stands. Any ideas?

my current code:

```
package daniel.work;

import java.applet.Applet;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.sun.opengl.util.JOGLAppletLauncher;

public class SimpleApplet extends JApplet {

  public void start(){
      try{
          SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){

                  add(ScatterCanvas.generateCanvas());

              }
          });
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
      }
  }
}
```

and

```
package daniel.work;

import java.awt.Canvas;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.demos.AbstractDemo;
import org.jzy3d.demos.Launcher;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Coord3d;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Scatter;


public class ScatterCanvas extends AbstractDemo{

    public static Canvas generateCanvas(){
            // Create the dot cloud scene and fill with data
            int size = 2000;
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
            float a;

            Coord3d[] points = new Coord3d[size];
            Color[]   colors = new Color[size];

            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                    x = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
                    y = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
                    z = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
                    points[i] = new Coord3d(x, y, z);
                    a = 0.25f + (float)(points[i].distance(Coord3d.ORIGIN)/Math.sqrt(1.3)) / 2;
                    colors[i] = new Color(x, y, z, a);
            }

            Scatter scatter = new Scatter(points, colors);
            chart = new Chart();
            chart.getScene().add(scatter);
            return (Canvas) chart.getCanvas();
    }


    protected static Chart chart;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Here's my code. I also changed my generateScatter to now return Chart "return chart" as opposed to ICavnas

```
package myjogl;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.controllers.mouse.ChartMouseController;
import org.jzy3d.chart.controllers.thread.ChartThreadController;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.ICanvas;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JzyApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

private Chart chart = null;
private ICanvas canvas = null;

public void init(){
    try{
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                chart = ScatterCanvas.generateCanvas(); //this just returns a chart object with a scatter object
                canvas = chart.getCanvas();

                add((Component) canvas);                
            }
        });     
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }   

    ChartMouseController mouse   = new ChartMouseController();

    chart.addController(mouse);


    ChartThreadController thread = new ChartThreadController();
    mouse.addSlaveThreadController(thread);
    chart.addController(thread);

    thread.start();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

public void zoom(){
    float value = canvas.getView().getBounds().getXmax()-10;
    canvas.getView().getBounds().setXmax(value);
    canvas.getView().shoot();
}


}
```